# 'UpdateMany' Mongo/PyMongo Bulkwrite deprecated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I am looking to update approximately 3000K entries their distance field, with 4000 values through PyMongo bulkwrite(), as update_many single is too slow.

My practice:

```
operations = []
for i in data:
    operations.append(updateMany({'location.zip':i['_id']}, {"$set":{'calculations.distance':i['distance']}}, upsert=True))
print(collection.bulk_write(operations, ordered=False))
```

where i = {'_id':'postal','distance':298.5}

This results in a

> NameError: name 'updateMany' is not defined

When I check [MongDB bulkWrite](https://mongoing.com/docs/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite.html#bulkwrite-write-operations-updateonemany):
It clearly shows:

> An array of bulkWrite() write operations.
>
> Valid operations are:
>
> - insertOne
> - updateOne
> - updateMany
> - deleteOne
> - deleteMany
> - replaceOne

Our dearly and beloved updateMany, which is written in 1000 ways in the past Mongo versions. However, is this not available anymore in PyMongo, and anyone know how to conquer this issue?

I have tried:

- updateMany
- UpdateMany
- update_many
- Update_Many
- updatemany

None have resulted in a good result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to guess; just read [the documentation](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/operations.html?highlight=updatemany#pymongo.operations.UpdateMany).

Try:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, UpdateMany

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

collection = db['collection']

data = [{'_id': 'postal', 'distance': 298.5}]

operations = []
for i in data:
    operations.append(
        UpdateMany({'location.zip': i['_id']}, {"$set": {'calculations.distance': i['distance']}}, upsert=True))

print(collection.bulk_write(operations, ordered=False))
```